# Oh-My-Zsh doesn't appear to see the path

Tags: zsh, path, oh-my-zsh

so I am attempting to use my path variable to find a file but it doesn't work. I am using zsh (oh-my-zsh particularly)

And i have the following commands in my .zshrc

```
export PATH=/Users/sidharthghoshal/TexmakerMacosx64:$PATH
#export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
#export PATH =usr:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I believe the last 3 commands do nothing. furthermore when i check to see the path

```
➜  ~  echo $path
/Users/sidharthghoshal/TexmakerMacosx64 /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Library/TeX/texbin
```

It seems to be in order. Yet somehow if I attempt to

```
➜  ~  open texmaker.app
The file /Users/sidharthghoshal/texmaker.app does not exist.
```

oh my zsh just isn't checking the directories inside the path. What am I missing?

Comment: ```➜  ~  which texmaker.app\n
texmaker.app not found```

Comment: I inserted the \n to indicate that it was on another line